# Variadic templates C++

Tags: c++, c, шаблоны-с++

есть следующий код:

```
#define concatenateStrings(destinationString, lenghtDestinationString, ...) \
     __concatenateStrings__(destinationString, lenghtDestinationString, ##__VA_ARGS__, NULL)

inline void __concatenateStrings__(char* destinationString, std::size_t lenghtDestinationString, const char* sourceStrings, ...) 
{
    va_list stringArguments;
    va_start(stringArguments, sourceStrings);
    std::fill(destinationString, destinationString + lenghtDestinationString, 0);
    for (const char* currentString = sourceStrings; currentString; currentString = va_arg(stringArguments, const char*))
        strcat_s(destinationString, lenghtDestinationString, currentString);
    va_end(stringArguments);
}
```

Можно ли его как-то переписать с использование Variadic Templates и на сколько это будет менее или более производительнее. Для раскрытия используется же рекурсия? Компилятор встроит этот код или будет постоянно вызывать рекурсию?

Comment: Если это С++, то почему не использовать `std::string`? Ради производительности?

Comment: Именно так, из С++ используются только некоторые фичи в проекте

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Можно ли его как-то переписать с использование Variadic Templates, и на сколько это будет менее или более производительнее

Разница должна быть минимальной. Правильно написанный шаблон медленнее точно не будет.

> Для раскрытия используется же рекурсия?

Совершенно не обязательно использовать рекурсию.

В соседнем ответе уже предложили довольно простое решение.
Вот более оптимизированный вариант, с проверкой на неправильные типы аргументов:

```
template <
    typename ...P,
    typename = std::enable_if_t<(std::is_convertible_v<P, const char *> && ...)>
>
void concatenateStrings(char *dest, std::size_t dest_size, const P &... params)
{
    dest_size--;

    auto lambda = [&](const char *str) -> bool
    {
        std::size_t str_size = std::strlen(str);

        bool no_more_space = 0;

        if (str_size >= dest_size)
        {
            no_more_space = 1;
            str_size = dest_size;
        }

        std::memcpy(dest, str, str_size);
        dest += str_size;
        dest_size -= str_size;

        return no_more_space;
    };

    (lambda(params) || ...);

    std::memset(dest, 0, dest_size+1);
}
```

Comment: За счет чего достигается оптимизация, по сравнению с предыдущим примером?

Comment: @QuickDzen Во-первых, не заполяется нулями та часть буфера, которую позднее займет строка. Во-вторых, так как мы убрали `strcat`, мы больше не пересчитываем длину временной строки на каждой итерации. В-третьих, если место в буфере заканчивается, мы не пытаемся вставить туда по-очереди все оставшиеся строки.

Answer (score 4):

Без использования `...`, обойтись можно:

```
template< typename ... T >
inline void concatenateStrings(char* destinationString, std::size_t lenghtDestinationString, T ... strings) 
{
    std::fill(destinationString, destinationString + lenghtDestinationString, 0);
    const char* stringsArray[] = { strings ... };
    for (const char* currentString : stringsArray )
        strcat_s(destinationString, lenghtDestinationString, currentString);
}
```

Можно записать еще короче:

```
template< typename ... T >
inline void concatenateStrings(char* destinationString, std::size_t lenghtDestinationString, T ... strings) 
{
    std::fill(destinationString, destinationString + lenghtDestinationString, 0);
    for (const char* currentString :  { strings ... } )
        strcat_s(destinationString, lenghtDestinationString, currentString);
}
```

Но, в этом случае, будем получать сложно читаемые сообщения об ошибках, в случае если аргументы функции имеют тип отличный от `const char*`.

Как видишь, можно обойтись без рекурсии. В данном случае, компилятор с высокой вероятностью встроит код и развернет цикл (в рекурсивной реализации - тоже), Но в общем случае, встраивание зависит от сложности функции.

По производительности - примерно тоже самое, что в исходном варианте (т.е. разница много меньше затрат на strcat_s, которые квадратичны по числу аргументов функции).

Comment: Спасибо большое) А можно ли как-то проверить разворот шаблонов?
Дизассемблером или есть еще какие-либо средства?

Comment: Посмотреть на полученный код в отладчике - самое надежно средство. Еще можно просить линкер генерировать  .map файл, и проверять в нем наличие сосуществующих функций, но это не дает гарантий что функция (не) встроилась.